# Integration by parts of $\varphi\operatorname{curl}(u)$

Tags: integration

Does anybody happen to know the integration by parts formula for $\int\varphi\operatorname{curl}(u)dV$, where $u$ is a 3D vector and $\varphi$ is a scalar? Is there a good reference for similar formulae?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_V \phi(\vec r)\nabla \times \vec u(\vec r)\,dV&=\int_V \left(\nabla \times(\phi(\vec r)\vec u(\vec r))-\nabla \phi(\vec r)\times \vec u(\vec r)\right)\,dV\\\\
&=\oint_S \phi(\vec r)\left(\hat n \times \vec u(\vec r)\right)\,dS-\int_V \nabla \phi(\vec r)\times \vec u(\vec r)\,dV
\end{align}$$

Comment: it worked perfectly!

Comment: Pleased to hear! And Happy Holidays!  -Mark

Comment: I have done so, but was informed that since my score is less than 15 my vote is recorded but not reflected. Sorry, will check later after i am promoted

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities) is a good reference. For your purpose, you need [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Product_of_a_scalar_and_a_vector)
$$\mathop{\rm curl}(\varphi {\bf u})= \varphi \mathop{\rm curl}({\bf u}) + (\mathop{\rm grad} \varphi) \times {\bf u}. $$

After interation, we obtain (employing Stokes' theorem)
$$ \int_\Omega \varphi \mathop{\rm curl}({\bf u})  \,dV =  \int_{\partial \Omega} \varphi \, \hat{\bf n} \times {\bf u}\, dS - \int_\Omega (\mathop{\rm grad} \varphi) \times {\bf u} \,dV .$$
Note that in typical applications, the surface integral $dS$ vanishes.

A reference for the Stokes' theorem follow [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410763/volume-integral-of-the-curl-of-a-vector-field).

Comment: That is flawed.  The surface integral as written is a scalar, while the volume integrals are vectors.

Comment: Yes, I think you meant cross product rather than dot product

Comment: This isn't really Stokes' Theorem, but rather a disguised Divergence Theorem.  ;-))