# How to convert an integration of a curl to the surface integral?

Tags: surface-integrals, line-integrals, curl

$\displaystyle\int \left[ \nabla \times \dfrac {M(r')}{r} \right] d\tau =\oint \dfrac{1}{r} \left[ M(r')×da' \right]$

I came across this integral from the David Griffiths introduction to electrodynamics, page no 278 ,fourth edition . But I really don't understand the procedure they came up with. It would be a great help if someone explains it step by step.

Comment: I would like a little more context here. For instance, what is $M$, and what are $r$ and $r'$? Are these integrals over curves, surfaces or volumes? Is the ambient space 2 or 3 dimensional? Without this kind of information, that equation could mean anything.

Comment: well here M means magnetic dipole moment, r' is unit vector and r is distance

Comment: at first it was volume integral then they converted to surface integral. I just dont understand the conversion procedure.

Comment: There are many theorems (with names like Gauss, Green and Stokes connected to them) that link some integral over a volume to a related integral over the surface of that volume, and they are all in some shape or form a version of the fundamental theorem of calculus. I think for you, [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410763/volume-integral-of-the-curl-of-a-vector-field) is a pretty good fit.

Comment: thank you! Really appreciate it.