Why does $\left(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla\right)\nabla\frac{1}{r}=\vec{a}\frac{4\pi}{3}\delta\left(\vec{r}\right)$?
I got this identity from a physics textbook, but figure the Math Stack Exchange could help.
Allegedly:
$$
\left(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla\right)\nabla\frac{1}{r}=\vec{a}\frac{4\pi}{3}\delta\left(\vec{r}\right)
$$
Where $r=\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{1/2}$ ans $\vec{a}$ is a constant vector. 
And I must have misunderstanding since when I carry out the computation,
$$
\nabla\frac{1}{r}=-\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}=-\hat{x}\frac{x}{r^3}-\hat{y}\frac{y}{r^3}-\hat{z}\frac{z}{r^3}
$$
$$
\left(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla\right)\nabla\frac{1}{r}=\left(
a_x\partial_x+a_y\partial_y+a_z\partial_z
\right)\left(
-\hat{x}\frac{x}{r^3}-\hat{y}\frac{y}{r^3}-\hat{z}\frac{z}{r^3}
\right)
$$
Using:
$$
\partial_x\frac{1}{r^3}=-3\frac{x}{r^5}
$$
I get, for the x-component of $\left(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla\right)\nabla\frac{1}{r}$:
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}\label{xComponent}
a_x\frac{-1}{r^3}+3a_x\frac{x^2}{r^5}+3a_y\frac{xy}{r^5}+3a_z\frac{xz}{r^5}
\end{equation}
I see how the x-component goes to $\infty$ when $\vec{r}=0$, but do not see how it is zero for arbitrary $\vec{r}\neq 0$ and the factors of $a_y$ and $a_z$ make it seem that the x-component of $\left(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla\right)\nabla\frac{1}{r}$ is not proportional to $a_x$.
Which brings me to my question:
Why does $\left(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla\right)\nabla\frac{1}{r}=\vec{a}\frac{4\pi}{3}\delta\left(\vec{r}\right)$?
By the way, the identity can be found in 2.8 of appendix F in Blundell's Magnetism in Condensed Matter .
Thanks all in advance

Are you sure $r$ in this context is $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}$? If this is the case there is no way that you can get the $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ factor.

I am quite sure $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. In the text it says "the factor of 3 is due to the fact that $\vec{S}$ picks out one out of the three components of the singularity", not sure if this helps.

I think it would help if you provide a copy of the full problem.

The identity $(S\cdot\nabla)\nabla\frac{1}{r}=S\frac{4\pi}{3}\delta(r)$ is stated on its own in the appendix, but your instinct is correct: the identity is meant to be used to show another identity which is part of a multi-part problem and I may be wrong in thinking I understand full context. I avoided the "bigger" identity since it would be asking more and the "smaller" identity seemed clear. I will consider posting the "bigger" identity and linking the two questions. After time, I may have to post the answer-this-exercise-for-me question on Physics Stack and find that I am missing context.

If you do the calculation then you should get $-\frac{1}{r^3}\left[\vec{a} - \frac{3(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{r})\vec{r})}{r^2}\right]$ for $r \not= 0$. This is more in line with what the question is asking you to prove.

The equality does not hold, but it could make sense (taken with a correct sign) if consider the integral with a finit function $\varphi(r)$:
$$\int_{R^3}\varphi(r)\left(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla\right)\nabla\frac{1}{r},d^3r=\color{red}{-},\vec{a},\frac{4\pi}{3}\varphi(0)$$

Get rid of the $\vec a$. The divergence of the inverse square field $\vec F = \vec r/r^3$ is $4\pi \delta(0)$. This is Gauss’s law.

First of all, the identity in the appendix of the book (i.e. the one from the question title) is definitely not correct, but there is more to it (and it is not just the sign error; as you have correctly shown, the LHS does not even vanish for $\mathbf{r}\neq 0$). A closer look at the problem reveals that what is really being asked is the remarkable identity
$$(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla)(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla)\frac{1}{r} = -\frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}}{r^3} + 3 \frac{(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{r})(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{r})}{r^5} - \frac{4\pi}{3} \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} \delta(\mathbf{r}).$$
The first part is just what you get from straight-forward vector calculus, so the interesting part is the $\delta(\mathbf{r})$.
The intuition behind the result comes from the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\frac{\mathbf{a}}{r}\right)\,\text{d}^3r = 4\pi \mathbf{a}\frac{2}{3}$$
that I will prove later.
First, note that given this integral, we find
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} (\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla) \nabla\frac{1}{r}\,\text{d}^3r = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \left[\nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\frac{\mathbf{a}}{r}\right) + \mathbf{a}\nabla^2 \frac{1}{r} \right]\,\text{d}^3r = 4\pi\mathbf{a} \frac{2}{3} - 4\pi \mathbf{a} = -\frac{4\pi}{3}\mathbf{a}.$$
Due to $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\mathbf{a}r^2 - 3\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{r})}{r^5}\,\text{d}^3r = 0$ (be careful with the $r$-integration and transform to a frame where $\mathbf{a}=a\mathbf{e}_z$ to show this), we thus find that the object
$$g(\mathbf{r}) = (\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla)(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla)\frac{1}{r} + \frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}}{r^3} - 3 \frac{(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{r})(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{r})}{r^5}$$
has the two properties
\begin{align}(1): &&g(\mathbf{r})&=0 \qquad \text{for }\mathbf{r}\neq 0, \\
(2): &&\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} g(\mathbf{r})\,\text{d}^3r &= -\frac{4\pi}{3}\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}.\end{align}
Combined, this means that $g(\mathbf{r}) \equiv -\frac{4\pi}{3}\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b} \delta(\mathbf{r})$ in the sense of
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \phi(\mathbf{r}) g(\mathbf{r})\,\text{d}^3r = -\frac{4\pi}{3}\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b} \phi(0)$$
for sufficiently "nice" functions $\phi$.
To solve the integral from above, use the usual vector identity combined with Gauss's law to get
\begin{align}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\frac{\mathbf{a}}{r}\right)\,\text{d}^3r &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \nabla\left(\nabla\cdot\frac{\mathbf{a}}{r}\right)\,\text{d}^3r - \mathbf{a}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \nabla^2\frac{1}{r}\,\text{d}^3r \\
&= \oint_{|\mathbf{r}|=R} \left( \nabla\cdot\frac{\mathbf{a}}{r} - \mathbf{a} \nabla\frac{1}{r} \right)\,\mathbf{e}_rr^2\text{d}\Omega \\
&= \oint_{|\mathbf{r}|=R} \left( 2\mathbf{a}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3} \right)\,\mathbf{e}_rr^2\text{d}\Omega\\
&= 2\oint_{|\mathbf{r}|=R} \left( \mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{e}_r \right)\,\mathbf{e}_r\text{d}\Omega\\
&= 2a\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos\theta\,\mathbf{e}_r\sin\theta\text{d}\theta\text{d}\varphi = 4\pi\mathbf{a}\frac{2}{3}. \end{align}
Similar to the other integral, justifying the simplifaction $\mathbf{a}=a\mathbf{e}_z$ requires a transform with the proper rotation matrix.

Thank you. I could follow every part of your solution except for the integral of $\nabla\times\nabla\times\frac{a}{r}$. For that , I used $\int\nabla\times Bd^3r=\oint dS \hat{n}\times B$ as can be seen in another stack answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410763/volume-integral-of-the-curl-of-a-vector-field

Ah yes, that is actually a bit more elegant!
